# Displaying dynamic content in bootstrap popover with angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that displays some fields from an object provided by a service using angular 2. I would like to display some of those fields only when the user hovers over some div. I thought the bootstrap popover would be ideal but I am not sure how to display those extra fields in the data-content element of the bootstrap popover. Here it is my attempt code.

```
div class="container">
  <div class="row">       
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Name">
      {{data.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A Date">
      {{data.aDate  | date:'shortDate'}}
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="other">
      {{data.other}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4" data-toggle="popover" title="More data" data-content="how to display data.field1, data.field2" >
      Popover test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the popover data-content I would like to display a multiple row that would look like

```
field1: {{data.field1}}
field2: {{data.field2}}
```

I am new to both bootstrap and angular, perhaps a popover is not even the best way to display this data?